# spaCy nlp - positions of entities in string, extracting nearby words

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

Lets say I have a string and want to mark some entities such as Organizations.

string = `I was working as a marketing executive for Bank of India, a 4 months..`

string_tagged = `I was working as a marketing executive for [Bank of India], a 4 months..`

I want to identify the words beside the entity tagged. 
How can I locate the positions of the entity tagged and extract the words beside the entity?

My code:

```python
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp(string)
company = doc.text
for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ == 'ORG':
        company = company[:ent.start_char] + company[:ent.start_char -1] +company[:ent.end_char +1] 
print company
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understood from your question you want words beside the `ORG` tagged token:

```python
import spacy    
nlp = spacy.load('en')
#string = "blah blah"
doc = nlp(string)
company = ""
for i in range (1, len(doc)-1)):
    if doc[i].ent.label_ == 'ORG':
        company = doc[i-1] + doc[i] + doc[i+1] # previous word, tagged word and next one            
print company
```

be aware of the first and last token checking.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as the error shows: TypeError 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @LenovoPast Are you sure you run my code correctly? because the error is not relevant to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me:

```
doc = nlp(str_to_be_tokenized)
company = []
for ent in doc.ents:
     if ent.label_ == 'ORG' and ent.text not in company:
         company.append(ent.text)
print(company)
```

The 2nd condition in if is to extract only unique company names in my block of text. If you remove that you'll get all instances of 'ORG' added to your company list. Hope this'll work for you as well